# How to make resource available to users with the corresponding userid

Tags: spring-boot, rest, authentication, keycloak, userid

i secured my backend (spring boot) as a resource server with keycloak and my frontend calls the resources on the backend with a jwt token in the header, meaning that when User1 makes a GET /products call a json structure like this is returned:

```
{
    "id": "639242400f6cc412b5b29f26",
    "userid": "f114298c-8b38-47e7-b413-bd8f12exyz",
    "productname": "productOne"
},
{
    "id": "63924a050f6cc412b5b29f27",
    "userid": "f114298c-8b38-47e7-b413-bd8f12exyz",
    "productname": "productTwo"

}, ....
```

When a logged in User creates a product, the userid that the currently logged in user has is assigned to the product. For example, User1 with the userid (f114298c-8b38-47e7-b413-bd8f12exyz) created productOne and productTwo.

My question is:
How do i make the products with the userid (f114298c-8b38-47e7-b413-bd8f12exyz) **only** available to the currently logged in User1 with the corresponding userid? So when User2 is logged in, he does not see the products assigned to User1. User2 only sees his own created products with the corresponding userid.

I hope I did not overcomplicate the question, thanks in advance!!

Comment: this should be fairly simple to do by using a database and creating a table for users and a table for products where the two are joined by userid (foreign key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your spring REST API as resource-server. If you don't know how, refer to [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote (it could also show you how to simplify your security conf if you already have a resource-server configured).

Then, when request is authorized, you should have a sub-class of `AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?>` in security context (unless you explicitly changed it like I do in 2nd and 3rd tutorials)

- `@EnableMethodSecurity` in your security-conf
- inject `AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?>` as controller method parameter

From that point, two options depending on your needs & preference (samples below are designed for a @Controller already decorated with `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`):

```java
@GetMapping("/products")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ_ANY_PRODUCT') || #auth.tokenAttributes['sub'] == #userid")
public List<ProductDto> listProducts(@RequestParam(required = true, name = "userid") @NotEmpty String userid, AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?> auth) {
    final var products = productRepo.findByUserid(userid);
    ....
}
```

or

```java
@GetMapping("/products")
public List<ProductDto> listProducts(AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?> auth) {
    final var products = productRepo.findByUserid(auth.getTokenAttributes().get(StandardClaimNames.SUB).toString());
    ...
}
```

If you follow the tutorials linked above until the 3rd, you'll learn how to build a custom DSL for Spring security expressions to build something like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("is(#userid) or isProductManager() or onBehalfOf(#userid).can('read_product')")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to do it with the AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?> and the second option that you have listed.

Comment: This 2nd option is perfect when you need no more than just filtering resources. If you encounter business requirements with complex access control, come back to the 3 tutorials linked, you'll save time and energy.

Comment: Hi ch4mp, i have got a question regarding jwt tokens: Why does the access token that i can see on my frontend (from browser inspection) look different than the token that i get when i make post request to http://localhost:8080/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token with the same username and password? The post request returns an access token with different payload. For example, the typ in the postman request is Bearer, whereas the typ in the frontend browser inspection is Serialized-ID

Comment: The POST to token endpoint probably returns 3 tokens (access, ID and refresh) are you looking at the right one? Also, each request to token endpoint should return a different set of tokens, even for same user (at least `iat` claim will change, which will also lead to a different signature)

Comment: when i put my access token from the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY Cookie into a jwt converter, i get following payload: exp, iat, jti, iss, sub, typ (Serialized-ID), session state, sid and state checker. My problem is: is it normal that i cant use the token from KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY Cookie to make requests like GET /products in postman? I always get 401 when i use that token, whereas the keycloak token endpoint works.

Comment: Yes, it is normal. This cookie is reserved for keycloak usage. Check the `aud` (audience) claim. The token to use when authorizing requests to your resource-server(s) is the **access** token from the response to token endpoint

Comment: Does that mean that when a User is logged in, he cannot use that KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY token to make requests that he shouldnt be able to do like for example: User A uses his KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY token to make a GET request to get the products of another User B. What exactly could a User do with the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY Cookie token?

Comment: This is not related. KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY is a private usage of Keycloak authorisation server when the kind of access-control o you are looking for

Comment: Can be achieved with role evaluation, or by comparing a unique identifier claim (like subject) with a value saved with the resource (a `createdBy` field or alike). This is demoed in the tutorials I already linked.

Comment: thanks for your help. So i should not worry about Users abusing the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY jwt token?

Comment: No you should not